# What is the origin of an external API call made by a firebase function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to make a call to an external api using a cloud function.
The external API requires me to register the origin of the call I am making with them.
For example https://mywebsite.com
What would the url to register with them be?
mywebsite.firebaseapp.com?
The domain name registered in firebase console, mywebsite.com?
Or something else like https://us-central1-mywebsite.cloudfunctions.net/functionName ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with massively scalable cloud products like Cloud Functions, you don't have guarantees about where your network traffic appears to come from.  Your source IP can (and will) change over time, and addresses of your project's DNS entries (for you cloudfunctions.net hostname) can be expected to change similarly.